# Error when installing necessary packages on Node js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, powershell, installation, msbuild

I was installing Node.js on Windows. It installed successfully, and I also selected the option to install necessary files (such as chocolatey) in the node.js installer. After node was installed, it opened up Powershell; after installing for a while, I got this error:

```
# A lot of logs before, just an excerpt
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler Microsoft.Component.MSBuild Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreBuildTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools
[5330:000f][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Decorating UnelevatedProductModifier with UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator
[5330:000f][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator
[5330:000e][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Download requested: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel
[5330:001d][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Attempting download 'https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel' using engine 'WebClient'
[5330:001d][2021-04-19T18:24:09] WebClient error 'RequestCanceled' with 'https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel' - GetWebResponse failed along with a cancellation request
[5330:001d][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Error 0x8013153b: [5330:001d][2021-04-19T18:24:09] Could not update channel "https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel"
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.WebClientEngine.GetWebResponse(Uri uri, DownloadContext downloadContext, DownloadSummary& downloadSummary, HttpWebRequest& webRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.WebClientEngine.DownloadCore(Uri uri, Stream stream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadEngineBase.DownloadWithBitRate(Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadEngineBase.Download(Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<Download>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ChannelManager.<GetLatestChannelManifestAsync>d__85.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ChannelManager.<UpdateChannelManifestAsync>d__77.MoveNext()
```

And nothing else is happening. What do I do?

Answer (score 28):

The additional tools install a number of items and their dependencies as mentioned when progressing through the script. These items would be used in case any node modules need to be compiled with these tools.

> This script will install Python and the Visual Studio Build Tools, necessary
> to compile Node.js native modules. Note that Chocolatey and required Windows
> updates will also be installed.
>
> This will require about 3 Gb of free disk space, plus any space necessary to
> install Windows updates. This will take a while to run.

Example for node-v16.13.0-x64.msi

```
- https://chocolatey.org/packages/chocolatey
- https://chocolatey.org/packages/python
- https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
```

In particular the visualstudio2019-workload-vctools involves the download of 1.6 gig of build tools, which can take awhile.

If you are wondering if things are progressing, try to launch **Visual Studio Installer**. If it is still running, you might get a message that says "Cannot start another instance of the installer while this instance is running."

If you've exited, rebooted, and relaunched the script and you're still wondering if all the tools got installed you can do the following:

- Type `choco list` to see if the packages `visualstudio-installer`, `visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`, and `visualstudio2019buildtools` are installed
- open the **Visual Studio Installer** and you can see if the installer has completed installing the build tools. It may need to be resumed. [image: Visual Studio Installer progress]

Note: updated to remove deprecated `-lo` from `choco list` command

Comment: thanks bro! good to know that there is something like Visual Studio Installer... when PowerShell stucks - the only thing that comes to mind is that something went wrong, but it should just open VS Installer so that users can track progress...

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the installation was stuck, as it took 7 minutes without any progress message. The limit isn't Internet speed here, so for some people it can take much longer.

Comment: By executing the command choco list -lo in PowerShell with Admin rights, I noticed all the packages are installed.

Comment: In my situation (with Windows 11) the VS Installer didn't start because the installation was still in progress. However I could see that the VS installer was running as a sub process of Chocolatey in the Task Manager.

Comment: Windows 10 here. It's worth noting that `"Cannot start another instance of the installer while this instance is running."` message will be in the "stuck" terminal, not a visual OS alert/popup. For me it seemed like launching the VS Installer did nothing but check the terminal for a message before reaching that conclusion.

Comment: BTW, `choco list -lo` errors: `Invalid argument -lo. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.` I'm not sure what those arguments did, but `choco list` by itself will list these packages, if they were installed.

Comment: choco list work for me without -lo parameter. Also VS Installer has a paused job, i remuse it.

Answer (score 12):

Same problem today. I just had Windows Powershell stop and freeze for about 5 minutes while installing Node.JS for VS Code (not Visual Studio). Last output from console is:

$ Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator

Long story short: I had to exit the terminal (did not like this action) and reboot the computer because the install program was still running.  Then I clicked on the installation file to run the Node.js Setup Wizard  (node-v15.14.0-x64.msi). There is a second option to repair the install attempt: "Repair". Click on that button and the install wizard completes the repair with full exit. The program notices that some elements have not been completed. Then you can run a javascript file at the terminal in VS Code.

I did not have to repair VS Code.

Sample run from VS Code Terminal (terminal entry in bold)

PS "Drive Location"\JavaScript> **node canDrinkNoIfs.js**

To run the script in VSC I need to open the folder (File -> open folder.) and then create a json file to run and debug code.  This json file is saved the .vscode subfolder.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\canDrinkNoifs.js"
    }]}
```

Comment: So are you using VSC or Node.js? Did you try to re-run the PowerShell script? If so, did you get an error again?

Comment: I am using Node.js.  I don't have a json file setup yet for the VSC.  The script is edited in VSC and then run with node in Windows Powershell. This is same way to working javascript in Linux.  Also I did not to run the install script for Node.  The Node.js Setup Wizard fixed the problem.  I do need to create a json file so I can use the run and debug  button in VSC.

Comment: EDIT: For me to run the script in VSC - open the folder for the script and save .vscode subfolder. (there may be a better method but this works for me.)  In VSC (1) File -> open folder (2) Run and Debug -> create a launch.json file -> select Node.js from dropdown. Script runs in VSC Debug Console & Terminal.

Comment: I also got the Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator. I also use Visual Code. It hung for at least 20 minutes.  It finally finished.

Answer (score 12):

it happens to me.

first try to use `space` or `tab`. in my first stop powershell

```
Download of vs_BuildTools.exe (1.4 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing visualstudio2017buildtools...
```

is working...

> guys if you use space or tab, and then work: this happens because you use the click-mouse in the PowerShell, don't do this, sometimes is pausing the program :) [if is working, is a normal error, and it don't cause nothing danger for completing the downloading]

but then I have a lot of white text.
the last stop is

```
[1968:0007][2021-08-24T19:47:57] Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator
```

[here the error you have.❌](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7hPA.png)

#### for correct this error... do this!

- go to edge (or the browser you choose for download)
- go to download tab, where there is `node-v14.17.5-x64.msi` (for edge is `CTRL+J`)
- OPEN FILE
- CLICK REPAIR
  and that's it

i will put some photos of final result if you need it:

[final result SUCCESS✅](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STeiA.png)

## EDIT

After a while i have this, in the same powershell i have the first stop.

```
Chocolatey timed out waiting for the command to finish. The timeout
 specified (or the default value) was '2700' seconds. Perhaps try a
 higher `--execution-timeout`? See `choco -h` for details.
  visualstudio2017-workload-vctools may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
The upgrade of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey upgraded 15/17 packages. 2 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Upgraded:
 - chocolatey-dotnetfx.extension v1.0.1
 - kb3033929 v1.0.5
 - visualstudio2017buildtools v15.9.38.0
 - chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension v1.0.4
 - vcredist140 v14.29.30133
 - kb2999226 v1.0.20181019
 - visualstudio-installer v2.0.1
 - kb2919355 v1.0.20160915
 - chocolatey-core.extension v1.3.5.1
 - kb2919442 v1.0.20160915
 - chocolatey-visualstudio.extension v1.9.0
 - vcredist2015 v14.0.24215.20170201
 - dotnetfx v4.8.0.20190930
 - kb3035131 v1.0.3
 - python v3.9.6

Failures
 - python3 (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
 - visualstudio2017-workload-vctools (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

and the last thing is [TYPE ENTER FOR EXIT - message on powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ast.png)

###### if you see the last message.

`See "choco -h" for details.`
so, i write it, in PowerShell.

**i have this result, with a green message, in the end, with the version**

```
This is a listing of all of the different things you can pass to choco.

Commands

 * list - lists remote or local packages
 * find - searches remote or local packages (alias for search)
 * search - searches remote or local packages (alias for list)
 * info - retrieves package information. Shorthand for choco search pkgname --exact --verbose
 * install - installs packages from various sources
 * pin - suppress upgrades for a package
 * outdated - retrieves packages that are outdated. Similar to upgrade all --noop
 * upgrade - upgrades packages from various sources
 * uninstall - uninstalls a package
 * pack - packages up a nuspec to a compiled nupkg
 * push - pushes a compiled nupkg
 * new - generates files necessary for a chocolatey package from a template
 * sources - view and configure default sources (alias for source)
 * source - view and configure default sources
 * config - Retrieve and configure config file settings
 * feature - view and configure choco features
 * features - view and configure choco features (alias for feature)
 * setapikey - retrieves, saves or deletes an apikey for a particular source (alias for apikey)
 * apikey - retrieves, saves or deletes an apikey for a particular source
 * unpackself - have chocolatey set itself up
 * version - [DEPRECATED] will be removed in v1 - use `choco outdated` or `cup <pkg|all> -whatif` instead
 * update - [DEPRECATED] RESERVED for future use (you are looking for upgrade, these are not the droids you are looking for)


Please run chocolatey with `choco command -help` for specific help on
 each command.

How To Pass Options / Switches

You can pass options and switches in the following ways:

 * Unless stated otherwise, an option/switch should only be passed one
   time. Otherwise you may find weird/non-supported behavior.
 * `-`, `/`, or `--` (one character switches should not use `--`)
 * **Option Bundling / Bundled Options**: One character switches can be
   bundled. e.g. `-d` (debug), `-f` (force), `-v` (verbose), and `-y`
   (confirm yes) can be bundled as `-dfvy`.
 * NOTE: If `debug` or `verbose` are bundled with local options
   (not the global ones above), some logging may not show up until after
   the local options are parsed.
 * **Use Equals**: You can also include or not include an equals sign
   `=` between options and values.
 * **Quote Values**: When you need to quote an entire argument, such as
   when using spaces, please use a combination of double quotes and
   apostrophes (`"'value'"`). In cmd.exe you can just use double quotes
   (`"value"`) but in powershell.exe you should use backticks
   (`` `"value`" ``) or apostrophes (`'value'`). Using the combination
   allows for both shells to work without issue, except for when the next
   section applies.
 * **Pass quotes in arguments**: When you need to pass quoted values to
   to something like a native installer, you are in for a world of fun. In
   cmd.exe you must pass it like this: `-ia "/yo=""Spaces spaces"""`. In
   PowerShell.exe, you must pass it like this: `-ia '/yo=""Spaces spaces""'`.
   No other combination will work. In PowerShell.exe if you are on version
   v3+, you can try `--%` before `-ia` to just pass the args through as is,
   which means it should not require any special workarounds.
 * **Periods in PowerShell**: If you need to pass a period as part of a
   value or a path, PowerShell doesn't always handle it well. Please
   quote those values using "Quote Values" section above.
 * Options and switches apply to all items passed, so if you are
   installing multiple packages, and you use `--version=1.0.0`, choco
   is going to look for and try to install version 1.0.0 of every
   package passed. So please split out multiple package calls when
   wanting to pass specific options.

Scripting / Integration - Best Practices / Style Guide

When writing scripts, such as PowerShell scripts passing options and
switches, there are some best practices to follow to ensure that you
don't run into issues later. This also applies to integrations that
are calling Chocolatey and parsing output. Chocolatey **uses**
PowerShell, but it is an exe, so it cannot return PowerShell objects.

Following these practices ensures both readability of your scripts AND
compatibility across different versions and editions of Chocolatey.
Following this guide will ensure your experience is not frustrating
based on choco not receiving things you think you are passing to it.

 * For consistency, always use `choco`, not `choco.exe`. Never use
   shortcut commands like `cinst` or `cup`.
 * Always have the command as the first argument to `choco. e.g.
   `choco install`, where `install` is the command.
 * If there is a subcommand, ensure that is the second argument. e.g.
   `choco source list`, where `source` is the command and `list` is the
   subcommand.
 * Typically the subject comes next. If installing packages, the
   subject would be the package names, e.g. `choco install pkg1 pkg2`.
 * Never use 'nupkg' or point directly to a nupkg file UNLESS using
   'choco push'. Use the source folder instead, e.g. `choco install
   <package id> --source="'c:\folder\with\package'"` instead of
   `choco install DoNotDoThis.1.0.nupkg` or `choco install DoNotDoThis
    --source="'c:\folder\with\package\DoNotDoThis.1.0.nupkg'"`.
 * Switches and parameters are called simply options. Options come
   after the subject. e.g. `choco install pkg1 --debug --verbose`.
 * Never use the force option (`--force`/`-f`) in scripts (or really
   otherwise as a default mode of use). Force is an override on
   Chocolatey behavior. If you are wondering why Chocolatey isn't doing
   something like the documentation says it should, it's likely because
   you are using force. Stop.
 * Always use full option name. If the short option is `-n`, and the
   full option is `--name`, use `--name`. The only acceptable short
   option for use in scripts is `-y`. Find option names in help docs
   online or through `choco -?` /`choco [Command Name] -?`.
 * For scripts that are running automated, always use `-y`. Do note
   that even with `-y` passed, some things / state issues detected will
   temporarily stop for input - the key here is temporarily. They will
   continue without requiring any action after the temporary timeout
   (typically 30 seconds).
 * Full option names are prepended with two dashes, e.g. `--` or
   `--debug --verbose --ignore-proxy`.
 * When setting a value to an option, always put an equals (`=`)
   between the name and the setting, e.g. `--source="'local'"`.
 * When setting a value to an option, always surround the value
   properly with double quotes bookending apostrophes, e.g.
   `--source="'internal_server'"`.
 * If you are building PowerShell scripts, you can most likely just
   simply use apostrophes surrounding option values, e.g.
   `--source='internal_server'`.
 * Prefer upgrade to install in scripts. You can't `install` to a newer
   version of something, but you can `choco upgrade` which will do both
   upgrade or install (unless switched off explicitly).
 * If you are sharing the script with others, pass `--source` to be
   explicit about where the package is coming from. Use full link and
   not source name ('https://chocolatey.org/api/v2' versus
   'chocolatey').
 * If parsing output, you might want to use `--limit-output`/`-r` to
   get output in a more machine parseable format. NOTE: Not all
   commands handle return of information in an easily digestible
   output.
 * Use exit codes to determine status. Chocolatey exits with 0 when
   everything worked appropriately and other exits codes like 1 when
   things error. There are package specific exit codes that are
   recommended to be used and reboot indicating exit codes as well. To
   check exit code when using PowerShell, immediately call
   `$exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE` to get the value choco exited with.

Here's an example following bad practices (line breaks added for
 readability):

  `choco install pkg1 -y -params '/Option:Value /Option2:value with
   spaces' --c4b-option 'Yaass' --option-that-is-new 'dude upgrade'`

Now here is that example written with best practices (again line
 breaks added for readability - there are not line continuations
 for choco):

  `choco upgrade pkg1 -y --source="'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2'"
   --package-parameters="'/Option:Value /Option2:value with spaces'"
   --c4b-option="'Yaass'" --option-that-is-new="'dude upgrade'"`

Note the differences between the two:
 * Which is more self-documenting?
 * Which will allow for the newest version of something installed or
   upgraded to (which allows for more environmental consistency on
   packages and versions)?
 * Which may throw an error on a badly passed option?
 * Which will throw errors on unknown option values? See explanation
   below.

Chocolatey ignores options it doesn't understand, but it can only
 ignore option values if they are tied to the option with an
 equals sign ('='). Note those last two options in the examples above?
 If you roll off of a commercial edition or someone with older version
 attempts to run the badly crafted script `--c4b-option 'Yaass'
 --option-that-is-new 'dude upgrade'`, they are likely to see errors on
 'Yaass' and 'dude upgrade' because they are not explicitly tied to the
 option they are written after. Now compare that to the other script.
 Choco will ignore `--c4b-option="'Yaass'"` and
 `--option-that-is-new="'dude upgrade'"` as a whole when it doesn't
 register the options. This means that your script doesn't error.

Following these scripting best practices will ensure your scripts work
 everywhere they are used and with newer versions of Chocolatey.


Default Options and Switches

 -?, --help, -h
     Prints out the help menu.

 -d, --debug
     Debug - Show debug messaging.

 -v, --verbose
     Verbose - Show verbose messaging. Very verbose messaging, avoid using
       under normal circumstances.

     --trace
     Trace - Show trace messaging. Very, very verbose trace messaging. Avoid
       except when needing super low-level .NET Framework debugging. Available
       in 0.10.4+.

     --nocolor, --no-color
     No Color - Do not show colorization in logging output. This overrides
       the feature 'logWithoutColor', set to 'False'. Available in 0.10.9+.

     --acceptlicense, --accept-license
     AcceptLicense - Accept license dialogs automatically. Reserved for
       future use.

 -y, --yes, --confirm
     Confirm all prompts - Chooses affirmative answer instead of prompting.
       Implies --accept-license

 -f, --force
     Force - force the behavior. Do not use force during normal operation -
       it subverts some of the smart behavior for commands.

     --noop, --whatif, --what-if
     NoOp / WhatIf - Don't actually do anything.

 -r, --limitoutput, --limit-output
     LimitOutput - Limit the output to essential information

     --timeout, --execution-timeout=VALUE
     CommandExecutionTimeout (in seconds) - The time to allow a command to
       finish before timing out. Overrides the default execution timeout in the
       configuration of 2700 seconds. '0' for infinite starting in 0.10.4.

 -c, --cache, --cachelocation, --cache-location=VALUE
     CacheLocation - Location for download cache, defaults to %TEMP% or value
       in chocolatey.config file.

     --allowunofficial, --allow-unofficial, --allowunofficialbuild, --allow-unofficial-build
     AllowUnofficialBuild - When not using the official build you must set
       this flag for choco to continue.

     --failstderr, --failonstderr, --fail-on-stderr, --fail-on-standard-error, --fail-on-error-output
     FailOnStandardError - Fail on standard error output (stderr), typically
       received when running external commands during install providers. This
       overrides the feature failOnStandardError.

     --use-system-powershell
     UseSystemPowerShell - Execute PowerShell using an external process
       instead of the built-in PowerShell host. Should only be used when
       internal host is failing. Available in 0.9.10+.

     --no-progress
     Do Not Show Progress - Do not show download progress percentages.
       Available in 0.10.4+.

     --proxy=VALUE
     Proxy Location - Explicit proxy location. Overrides the default proxy
       location of ''. Available for config settings in 0.9.9.9+, this CLI
       option available in 0.10.4+.

     --proxy-user=VALUE
     Proxy User Name - Explicit proxy user (optional). Requires explicity
       proxy (`--proxy` or config setting). Overrides the default proxy user of
       ''. Available for config settings in 0.9.9.9+, this CLI option available
       in 0.10.4+.

     --proxy-password=VALUE
     Proxy Password - Explicit proxy password (optional) to be used with
       username. Requires explicity proxy (`--proxy` or config setting) and
       user name.  Overrides the default proxy password (encrypted in settings
       if set). Available for config settings in 0.9.9.9+, this CLI option
       available in 0.10.4+.

     --proxy-bypass-list=VALUE
     ProxyBypassList - Comma separated list of regex locations to bypass on
       proxy. Requires explicity proxy (`--proxy` or config setting). Overrides
       the default proxy bypass list of ''. Available in 0.10.4+.

     --proxy-bypass-on-local
     Proxy Bypass On Local - Bypass proxy for local connections. Requires
       explicity proxy (`--proxy` or config setting). Overrides the default
       proxy bypass on local setting of 'True'. Available in 0.10.4+.

     --log-file=VALUE
     Log File to output to in addition to regular loggers. Available in 0.1-
       0.8+.
Chocolatey v0.10.15
```

the most important thing is:

`Chocolatey v0.10.15`

[chocolatey v.0.10.15 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86rWJ.png)

## ok, let test if npm is installed :)

first at all write: `npm -version`

if return a version, you are fine!!!!

now you can install from npm!

for example: me installing tailwindcss

- go to website of tailwindcss [image: tailwind website]
- copy the npm code [image: npm code] `npm install tailwindcss`
- go to vs code and paste it.

  PS C:\Users\laaou\Desktop> npm -version
  6.14.14
  PS C:\Users\laaou\Desktop> npm install tailwindcss
  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\laaou\package.json'
  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\laaou\package.json'
  npm WARN tailwindcss@2.2.7 requires a peer of autoprefixer@^10.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN laaou No description
  npm WARN laaou No repository field.
  npm WARN laaou No README data
  npm WARN laaou No license field.
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- tailwindcss@2.2.7
  updated 1 package and audited 180 packages in 3.857s

17 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

PS C:\Users\laaou\Desktop>
[image: succesfull download on vs code]

- then try use npm fund if you are curious

Comment: Which version of Windows are you doing this on? `kb3033929 v1.0.5` appears in your quoted Powershell text, and that's a Windows 7 update according to microsoft.com. (I'm asking because I've noticed this appearing on my Windows 10 PC.)

Comment: Following on from that... 3033929 may not actually be a problem. https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/kb3033929 states *"On systems other than Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, this package installs successfully, but
does nothing."* However, no such reassurance is given on the Chocolatey page for KB2999226, which is also in your PS output.

Comment: The space worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me also.
As long as setup processes proceed, I think those specific errors are insignificant. It may take a while to complete, as it uses much Network and CPU. If all setup processes are done and the last message in terminal is the one shared, you probably paused it with your cursor. Just press `space` or `enter` and the terminal will release.
[image]

Comment: Pausing the process with your cursor would cause errors?

Comment: @code negative, i meant that the process might be done already, but the log wasn't flushed to terminal because it was paused

Answer (score 0):

the same when this happens, close the window and before restarting or doing anything else, check the node version in the CMD, if the version you selected when downloading appears, everything went well, if nothing appears, then if you should try by other means, sometimes it stays like this because it doesn't give a completed response, that's how the windows power shell is... (it always happens to me).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell and Command prompt both hang for me for various reasons and while trying to run various commands (gpupdate /force, etc.)

One thing that has helped me is just tapping on the up arrow. Sometimes that's all it needs to kick it into gear.

The up arrow trick worked for me while trying to install Node.js and the needed prerequisites on a 10-year old Lenovo running Windows 10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).